# Where can I find kCGKeyboardEventKeycode list of key codes for Cyrillic language

Tags: objective-c, c, api

Not even sure where to put this question. This is a piece of code that I found.

```
CGEventRef myCGEventCallback(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, void *refcon) {
    //0x0b is the virtual keycode for "b"
    //0x09 is the virtual keycode for "v"
    if (CGEventGetIntegerValueField(event, kCGKeyboardEventKeycode) == 0x0B) {
        CGEventSetIntegerValueField(event, kCGKeyboardEventKeycode, 0x09);
    }

    return event;
}
```

you can find the whole code in here http://pastebin.com/eJ9PYPAZ.

It swaps one letter with another "globally" in any application. What i want is to be able to change latin letter with a cyrillic one. kCGKeyboardEventKeycode uses keys to access an integer field that contains the virtual keycode of the key-down or key-up event. For example 0x0b is the virtual keycode for "b". What is the virtual key code for Cyrillic letter "б"?

My problem is that I'm unable to find list of key codes for Cyrillic alphabet anywhere on the net, as if they do not exist. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as a virtual keycode for a Cyrillic letter, as far as I know.

Virtual keycodes don't indicate which character would be generated by the key.  They indicate the key position by referencing one of a small number of standard keyboard models (ANSI, ISO, or JIS).

So, for example, `kVK_ANSI_B` (0x0b; the constant is defined in `<Carbon/HIToolbox/Events.h>`) is a reference to that place on an ANSI keyboard where the "B" key is.  That is, it references the position that's roughly in the middle of the bottom row of keys.  However, it doesn't mean the key which is labeled "B" or that produces a "b" character.  The character that's produced is a function of the currently-selected keyboard layout, which is controlled by software and can change at any time.  The label is irrelevant to the computer (although helpful to the user).

In other words, the virtual keycode is similar to the hardware scan code but is "virtual" in that it has been abstracted away from any actual physical keyboard.  It references an idealized keyboard.

So, to address what you're trying to accomplish, you want to specify the virtual keycode for the key position which would produce "б" when a Russian/Cyrillic keyboard layout is in use.  From what I can tell by selecting the Russian keyboard layout that ships with OS X, that would be `kVK_ANSI_Comma` (0x2b).

Comment: Unfortunately it produces ',' symbol. I think this would not be possible to do with this approach. As you saying for it to work the Russian layout must be in use. I'm trying to develop transliteration application, but I'm not sure where to start and how to approach this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a transliteration application or how you want it to work. Maybe you want to create a keyboard layout, instead. Take a look at [Ukulele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) for that. The event tap approach may work if you use `CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString()` to set the desired string, although usually the keycode is translated through the keyboard layout.

Comment: My plan is to build something similar to LetterZu. It is a transliteration application that runs in the background and transliterates Latin characters to Cyrillic on the fly. If I type "privet" the application will transliterate this to "привет". Ukulele is great, but complicated for the average user. Thats why I want to create something that sits in the background and intercepts key presses and transliterates them according to predefined set of rules. Hope this explains the idea.

Comment: To clarify, I wasn't suggesting that the end user would use Ukulele. Rather that you would use it to create a keyboard layout for your end users. I wouldn't think that installing a keyboard layout would be particularly complicated for users. Recall that having an event tap receive key events requires the user to enable access for assistive devices, which also requires a trip to System Preferences. *shrug*

Comment: Yes that is true, I was thinking about it. The access for assistive devices must be enabled.  But so many useful apps require to do this. One of them is PopClip and Window Tidy. So I guess that is the way with apple. Anyways thanks for your help. Back to drawing board for me as I still have no idea how to approach this :)